# How to freez Y rotation in unity transform.LookAt()?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;



public class FollowPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;

    private void Update()
    {
        transform.LookAt(target);
    }
}
```

I need to delete Y rotation in LookAt, help me!

(Im add some iformation cose STACKL OVERFLOW want some more information from me)

Comment: https://answers.unity.com/questions/135505/look-at-target-without-y.html

Comment: im stupid, i dont understanded anything from this link.... please write full code to me, i dumb for this

Comment: You don't want to rotate around the Y axis? Or you don't want to take position differences on the Y axis into account?

Answer (score 0):

im guessing what you're implying is zeroing out the y axis.

in that case, after you call your LookAt, you want to reset the y axis

YOURS

```
private void Update()
{
    transform.LookAt(target);
    //reset the y axis here.
}
```

FIXED

```
private void Update()
{
    transform.LookAt(target);
    transform.rotation.y = 0;
    //make sure to call that after LookAt, otherwise it will override the other line
}
```

i'd recommend you watch a few tutorials instead of being fed code.